# Regex statement to replace spaces with underscore between words starting with Capital Letter

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

With input like:

> Roger Federer is a tennis player. Rafael Nadal Parera is also a tennis player. Another legend player is Novak Djokovic.

I am expecting an output like:

> Roger_Federer is a tennis player. Rafael_Nadal_Parera is also a tennis player. Another legend player is Novak_Djokovic.

A solution I've tried using positive lookbehind (using Python `re` package) is:

```
re.sub(r"(?<=\w)\s([A-Z])", r"_\1", above_string)
```

But here, because of `\w`, I get an output:

> Roger_Federer is a tennis player. Rafael_Nadal_Parera is also a tennis player. Another legend player **is_Novak_Djokovic**.

Naturally, I can't make it work using `r"(?<=[A-Z]\w*)\s([A-Z])"`, because

> error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

I have to apply this regex on huge number of (and much diverse) articles so I can't afford any loop or a `str.replace` bruteforce. I was wondering if anyone could please come with with an **efficient solution**.

Comment: but how do you know that a non-regex solution would not be more efficient - have you actually implemented a solution using loops for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about all Unicode uppercase letters, you can use

```py
import re
above_string = "Roger Federer is a tennis player. Rafael Nadal Parera is also a tennis player. Another legend player is Novak Djokovic."
print( re.sub(r"\b([A-Z]\w*)\s+(?=[A-Z])", r"\1_", above_string) )
# => Roger_Federer is a tennis player. Rafael_Nadal_Parera is also a tennis player. Another legend player is Novak_Djokovic.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HW90dU). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PwPQGg/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([A-Z]\w*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): an uppercase letter and zero or more word chars
- `\s+`  - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=[A-Z])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with an uppercase letter.

If you need to support all Unicode letters, it is advisable to `pip install regex` and use

```py
import regex
above_string = "Roger Federer is a tennis player. Rafael Nadal Parera is also a tennis player. Another legend player is Novak Djokovic."
print( regex.sub(r"\b(\p{Lu}\w*)\s+(?=\p{Lu})", r"\1_", above_string) )
# => Roger_Federer is a tennis player. Rafael_Nadal_Parera is also a tennis player. Another legend player is Novak_Djokovic.
```

See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##ZY9PC4JAEMXvforB01ohRGeJIDqFhGdBxpzM3HaW3dWS6LPblh2CTm/@/Jj3Rg/uzGo1js1Vs3FgqKZ7gCX3VFhnGlVDAmHGNRnYUUXGa2MBwZFSvtASBzIxZHhCkpBihRIO6DH8cNLyP7xR7M7@kPRmqvqO33jKPbawvXDLfXOMw0D7BE5MqWLblcKEeSly/dh3z/w2i3I7F@tk6qNwAX69LLz@PhBBNI4v). Here, `\p{Lu}` matches any Unicode uppercase letter.